# Trying out media queries and can't get them to work

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am fairly new to CSS and am trying out media queries. I have followed many people's advice on other posts here on Stackoverflow and other websites but can't get them to work.
I am simply trying to change the colour of boxes when the screen goes below a certain width.
Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" name"viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
  </head>
  <body>
    <span class="boxes" id="b1">Box 1</span>
    <span class="boxes" id="b2">Box 2</span>
    <span class="boxes" id="b3">Box 3</span>
    <span class="boxes" id="b4">Box 4</span>
    <span class="boxes" id="b5">Box 5</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS file:

```
.boxes {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  color: #FFF;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 80px;
  margin: 20px;
  top: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:600px) {
  .boxes {
    background-color: #000000;
  }
}
```

**I have tried:**
 * `@media screen` **without** the `only` word in the CSS file.
 * No `media="screen"` in the html link tag.
 * `max-device-width` in the CSS file.
 * `media="only screen and (max-device-width: 600px)"` in the HTML link tag.

Nothing I have tried has worked, what am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried `min-width`? Perhaps even the `!important` flag

Comment: just tested and it is working, your problem is in your CSS file overriding this property

Comment: @WesFoster don't advise to use `!important`

Comment: What hasn't worked? With what you've provided, the boxes should be black if the width of the browser is below 600 pixels.

Comment: @dippas It's for debugging the issue. If I think it will get the OP closer to determining the problem, I will advise it.

Comment: that's the worst advise you can give to anyone who is starting in CSS. That's not a way to debug CSS

Comment: @dippas If `!important` does not touch it, then we know that the issue lies in something higher, perhaps the media query itself. However, if the `!important` flag did cause it to work, then we can deduce that perhaps there is some other style overriding the media query's changes. Debugging in action.

Comment: by looking to the media query  it looks prefect, so it will work (using `!important` will always get flagged in this case, because this is a CSS Specificity Problem..

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the equal sign in your viewport meta tag. Your code will work when you place it. name = "viewport"

Comment: In your example you completely took meta viewport out. You should put it back in with correct syntax and it will work!

Comment: I took it out to show it that it works without the meta tag

Comment: My bad, I thought it was yasgreen's comment. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to change the `<meta>` tag to:

```
 <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

You could try specifying the background color:

```
@media screen and (min-width:601px) {
.boxes {
  background-color: red;
  }
}
```

Again, yours works for me as is, but maybe by specifying the background color of red only above 601px will work.

```css
.boxes {
  display: inline-block; /* Added this so they don't overlap */
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  color: #FFF;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 80px;
  margin: 20px;
  top: 100px;
  position: relative;
  
}
@media screen and (min-width:601px) {
.boxes {
  background-color: red;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
  .boxes {
    background-color: #000000;
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="boxes" id="b1">Box 1</span>
<span class="boxes" id="b2">Box 2</span>
<span class="boxes" id="b3">Box 3</span>
<span class="boxes" id="b4">Box 4</span>
<span class="boxes" id="b5">Box 5</span>
```

Comment: meta tag is not the issue here http://serpa.eusou.com/SO/bts.html, and that additional media query you tested won't do much

Comment: What is the issue then? Is there a certain scenario in which the boxes aren't changing color? I'm not having issues when testing it, so it's hard to understand what the problem is.